# Wakeup script is not launching Chromium-Browser (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: command-line, scripts, suspend, chromium, wakeup

I need to open browser on a certain page each time the laptop wakes up from hibernate / sleep and on boot.

I've created a script wakeUp.sh in folder `/lib/systemd/system-sleep/`
made `chmod 777 /lib/systemd/system-sleep/wakeUp.sh` to give all rights to the file for sure.

**Now the script it self** (where I try to make the browser open on page after I close-open the laptop lid [sleep-wakeup]):

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "$@" > /tmp/wakeUpParams.txt
case $1/$2 in
post|*)
    chromium-browser --no-sandbox http://google.com 1>/home/liza/out.txt 2>/home/liza/err.txt
    echo "$@" > /tmp/AfterBrowserLaunch.txt
    ;;
esac
```

In the script, I save the output of the incoming parameters to a `/tmp` folder, and after I close/open the lid I find these params in txt file:

```
post suspend
```

Thus the param $1 = post and $2 = suspend

If I run the script from terminal:

```
sudo ./wakeUp.sh
```

or

```
sudo ./wakeUp.sh post suspend
```

It runs successfully. So it executes the line where the browser is opened.

If I close/open the lid, the params in wakeUpParams.txt are still `post suspend` and the `echo "$@" > /tmp/AfterBrowserLaunch.txt` line also executes, but the browser still doesn't launch.

Now to the errors:

**When I execute the script via terminal** the browser launches but I get errors in the err.txt file:

```
    Home directory not accessible: Permission denied
[13870:13961:0316/181921.003202:ERROR:bus.cc(394)] Failed to connect to the bus: Could not parse server address: Unknown address type (examples of valid types are "tcp" and on UNIX "unix")

(chromium-browser:13870): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Unable to get session bus: Unknown or unsupported transport 'disabled' for address 'disabled:'
[13870:13870:0316/181922.813336:ERROR:gpu_process_transport_factory.cc(1009)] Lost UI shared context.
[13968:14061:0316/181923.018813:ERROR:cmd_buffer_helper.cc(158)] ContextResult::kFatalFailure: CommandBufferHelper::AllocateRingBuffer() failed
```

The out.txt is empty.

**When the lid is closed/opened:**

- out.txt - empty
- err.txt - empty ( Why no errors here? )

I also execute `chromium-browswer` with `--no-sandbox` params `chromium-browser --no-sandbox` because it wouldn't start without this param from terminal due to some security issues. Is this normal way to start it? Because the browser says in a yellow message pop-out: "You are using an unsupported command-line flag: --no-sandbox. Stability and security will suffer." Is this the best way to execute `chromium-browser` from the command-line?

**Update 1**

I changed `chromium-browser` to a simple text editor `gedit` and it still won't start even Gedit on open/close lid, while the script from terminal runs without problem... So I suppose it's not a problem with Chromium...

**Update 2**

Starting to understand that it's a bad idea to mess with launching GUI from systemd. See [Launching Chromium on startup with systemd - Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/385964/launching-chromium-on-startup-with-systemd)

Comment: The scripts `/lib/systemd/system-sleep/` get run as root I believe, my guess is that chrome does not like that. If you runs the script as your user, it should work. I'm not sure how to do that through.

Comment: I changed chromium-browser to a simple text editor "gedit" and it still won't start even "Gedit" on open/close lid ... While the script from terminal runs without problem ... So I suppose it's not the problem with chromium  ....